# Can you alter your hearing range by changing air pressure in your nose?

Tags: hearing, human-ear

I caught a bad cold recently and found that increasing air pressure in my nose causes some clicks in my ear. I understood from this site that this is because ears and nose are connected. But what I didn't understand however, was that I my hearing range got completely shifted after doing so (not permanently of course). If I am right, it tends to make low frequency sounds clearer. The opposite happens when I decrease pressure. The higher frequencies become more crip and clear. I have the feeling that the answer is related to the way hearing works but would like to hear how exactly. It would be great if any of you could confirm or deny this or provide some explanations.

Comment: Questions based on personal anecdotes are hard to answer. Perceptual quality of sound may depend on a lot of things besides middle ear pressure.

Comment: Just fyi: the ear(s) and the nose are connected by the eustachian tube, not the sinuses.

Comment: @AliceD Agreed. I have also experienced the shift in audible range while travelling on a plane. This is why I think this is related to pressure.

Comment: Thanks for the info @anongoodnurse

Comment: The sound equation I = Xi^2.Omega^2.c.Rho (Xi = particle displacement, Omega = frequency, c = speed of sound, Rho = density of medium)  implies that the sound pressure (i.e. volume) changes with air pressure  and frequency- which explains the aeroplane problem, but I don't know how much effect in the small volume of an ear.